# My iPhone is giving unexpected, creepy reminders

Tags: iphone

My iPhone keeps popping up with creepy reminders such as:

> 'shes there' 'check the bedroom' 'i know what school you go to'

However, I haven't set any reminders on my phone ever and do not use the Reminders App. I'm confused as to what is happening. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3):

There are two options that are most likely.

#### Option #1:

Someone has gained access to your iCloud account and has been adding reminders remotely. If this is the case, you should be grateful that they are just adding reminders as they could do *far* more.

#### Solution #1:

Reset your iCloud password immediately and set up two-factor authentication.

#### Option #2:

Someone has gained physical access to your iPhone and either knows the password or your phone is unprotected.

#### Solution #3:

Change your phone password to something other than 1234, and make sure that it is enabled all the time.

Lastly, remove the reminders.

Comment: The appleid password can be changed at https://appleid.apple.com